# File Explorer- I'm not able to open a file in our shared drive but if I copy it to my desktop I can. Why is that?

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems

If I go through my company's shared drive and look for a specific file. I am able to locate it and try to open it with Chrome, PDF, etc but it won't actually open. If using Chrome it'll show that the file has been moved or deleted. With that being said if I copy it to say my desktop it will open and does have a size on disk.

I looked at the properties of the file when it is in the original location and I can see that it has a file size but it doesn't have a size on disk. I did some digging around google and saw that this might be due to data deduplication but I searched the whole drive and found no other instance of this file. I also did some testing and noticed that the file is openable if I start putting it in other random folders.

[You can see for some reason the beginning name starts with a "?" as well as the size on disk being 0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmjt0.jpg)

For example TEST > TEST2 > TEST3 > TEST4 > TEEST>5 > Doesn't open

but TEST > TEST2 > TEST3 > Opens

Someone had suggested the file was too deep down but I've never seen or have had anyone have any issues like this and we typically have files that are folders and folders deep.

*Update* I noticed that if I copy one of the versions that work with a much smaller name then it will open. I however am not able to rename the original file. It will just revert back to it's original name.

Comment: What does your Company Tech Support say?

Comment: I'm the helpdesk for the company. We have an MSP we work with but they haven't responded to our emails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you, for test purposes, create another mount point deeper into the tree structure and then have it work as you expect? i.e. add map such that your file is `Q:\test4\test5\5`

Comment: I think max_path is 260 (with drive letter, colon, slash and terminating null this leaves 256)?

Comment: with win 10 it can be increased: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd

Comment: `\\?\ ` tells Windows the program can handle paths up to 32K of characters . IE The programmer will allocate 64kb of memory for the filename rather than the standard 520 bytes. It is 2 bytes per character. Windows enforces 260 characters as that is what 99% of programs can use. Opening a filename of longer than 260 characters will cause a buffer overrun in 99% of programs *if it was allowed*. Programmers have to opt in for longer names.

Comment: I kept reading the file into the folder and naming it 123456789.pdf and that wouldn't open. I then attempted 12345678.pdf and that did. I'm lead to believe that it is a 260 character limit but I'm surprised as previously I would just get an error message stating so.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of it, but opening it directly "in place" doesn't work.
That is usually caused by the file being locked by someone else on the network.

That doesn't mean that is actively in-use by someone. It is possible that someone had it open previously (could even have been yourself) and it wasn't properly closed. That sometimes happens if the application that had it open crashed or someone disconnected the computer without closing the file first.

There is no way you can solve this from the client side.
The administrator of the file-server needs to forcibly close it on the file-server side.
It is also possible that the file is released automatically after a set time (24 or 48 hours is fairly typical). Some file-server systems can be configured to do that.
A reboot of the file-server will release the file too.